# How is exponential martingale the solution of $d Y_t=Y_t d M_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm reading about exponential martingale from these [notes](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf).

---

**4.1 Exponential martingale**

Let $M$ be a continuous square-integrable martingale and let $Y$ be the process defined as
$$
Y_t=\exp \left(M_t-\frac{\langle M\rangle_t}{2}\right), \quad t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}.
$$

Notice that $Y$ is not necessarily a martingale, a priori.

**Fact.** (to be proven later) If there exists a constant $K>0$ such that
$$
\langle M\rangle_t \leq K t \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, \quad \quad (3)
$$
then $Y$ is a continuous square-integrable martingale. $Y$ is said to be the exponential martingale associated to $M$.

**Example.** If $M_t=B_t$, then $\langle B\rangle_t=t$ and $Y_t=\exp \left(B_t-\frac{t}{2}\right)$ is indeed a martingale.

**Remarks.**

- There exists a more general condition than (3) which ensures that the process $Y$ is a martingale up to a finite time horizon $T>0$. This more general condition, called Novikov's condition, reads:
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(\exp \left(\frac{\langle M\rangle_T}{2}\right)\right)<\infty .
  $$
- Under condition (3), one can apply Ito-Doeblin's formula to conclude that
  $$
  Y_t=1+\int_0^t Y_s d M_s \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}_{+} .
  $$
  i.e., $Y$ is solution of the SDE:
  $$
  d Y_t=Y_t d M_t, \quad Y_0=1.
  $$

---

> Could you explain how to get
> $$
> Y_t=1+\int_0^t Y_s d M_s \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}_{+} .
> $$
> under (3)?

Comment: I don't think you need condition (3) to conclude that.  Just apply Ito's formula to $Y_t$ to get $Y_t = Y_0 + \int_0^t Y_s dM_s$.  To get $Y_0 = 1$, it looks like you need $M_0=0$, but that doesn't follow from condition (3) either.

Comment: @user6247850 Assume $(Y_t, t \in [0, T])$ is a continuous square-integrable martingale and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ twice continuously differentiable. By Ito's lemma, $f\left(Y_t\right)-f\left(Y_0\right)=\int_0^t f^{\prime}\left(Y_s\right) \mathrm{d} Y_s+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f^{\prime \prime}\left(Y_s\right) \mathrm{d}\langle Y\rangle_s$. I could not see how to pick $f$ to get the desired result...

Comment: @user6247850 I guess the author forgot to include $M_0=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x,y) := e^{x-\frac 12 y}$ and observe that $Y_t = f(M_t, \langle M\rangle_t).$  Now, Ito's formula gives
\begin{align*}
Y_t &= f(M_t, \langle M\rangle_t) \\
&= 1+ \int_0^t \partial_x f(M_s,\langle M\rangle_s) dM_s + \int_0^t \partial_y f(M_s,\langle M\rangle_s)d\langle M\rangle_s + \frac 12 \int_0^t \partial_{xx} f(M_s,\langle M\rangle_s) d\langle M\rangle_s \\
&= 1 + \int_0^t f(M_s,\langle M\rangle_s) dM_s -\frac 12 \int_0^t f(M_s,\langle M\rangle_s)d\langle M\rangle_s + \frac 12 \int_0^t f(M_s,\langle M\rangle_s) d\langle M\rangle_s \\
&= 1 + \int_0^t Y_s dM_s.\end{align*}

There are no second order cross terms because $\langle M\rangle_t$ has finite variation.

Comment: The usual Itô's lemma I have seen so far is $$\begin{aligned}
& f\left(t, M_t\right)-f\left(0, M_0\right) \\
= & \int_0^t f_t^{\prime}\left(s, M_s\right) \mathrm{d} s+\int_0^t f_x^{\prime}\left(s, M_s\right) \mathrm{d} M_s+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f_{x x}^{\prime \prime}\left(s, M_s\right) \mathrm{d} s.
\end{aligned}$$

Could you provide me with a reference containing the version you have used?

Comment: Karatzas and Shreve's _Brownian motion and Stochastic Calculus_, Revuz and Yor's _Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion_, or just using the integration by parts formula in the notes you provided.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!